# How do I create an IFeature object from an IPolyline or ILine object

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, c#

I am having some problems with some code i am trying to write. The application i am creating allows the user to click on the map and a point will be createD, when they click again to create another point a line is created between the two points.

The code i have got at the moment is

```
for (int i = 0; i < pointCollection.PointCount - 1; i++)
{
    //create the line from the points
    ILine pLine = new Line();
    pLine.PutCoords(pointCollection.Point[i], pointCollection.Point[i + 1]);

    IPolyline newPolyline = new PolylineClass();
    newPolyline.FromPoint = pLine.FromPoint;
    newPolyline.ToPoint = pLine.ToPoint;

    //create a feature ****STUCK HERE****
    IFeature newline = new PolylineClass() as IFeature; ;
    newline.Shape = newPolyline;


    geometriesToUnion.AddGeometry(newline.Shape as IGeometry);
}
resultPolyline.ConstructUnion(geometriesToUnion as IEnumGeometry);
```

Has anyone got any idea if this is possible or a another way of doing it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't instantiate an `IFeature` like that. You can only get it from other interfaces.

From your code, I'm having trouble understanding why you need an `IFeature`. You can carry on without it, since you are just dealing with Geometries.

In case you are trying to create a new feature in a Featureclass, I'll suggest that you have a look at the following document: [Creating features](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/d/00010000049v000000.htm)

Ideal, we would use some code like this:

```
public static void CreateFeature(IFeatureClass featureClass, IPolyline polyline)
{
  // Build the feature.
  IFeature feature = featureClass.CreateFeature();
  feature.Shape = polyline;    

  // Update the value on a string field that indicates who installed the feature.
  int contractorFieldIndex = featureClass.FindField("CONTRACTOR");
  feature.set_Value(contractorFieldIndex, "K Johnston");

  // Commit the new feature to the geodatabase.
  feature.Store();
}
```

Comment: Devdatta, yes you are right, I don't need to use the `IFeature` object. The code is now doing what it needs to, so thanks alot!